# Escape quotes in batch script variable

Tags: windows, escaping, batch-file

How do you escape quotes in a variable to compare with another one.

Example: A script outputs "The output of "test.exe" is OK" (without the surrounding quotes)

In a batch script I save the output in a variable in my batch script and then want to compare with a saved variable.

```
set ouputTest1 = "The output of "test.exe" is OK"

test.exe -p 75 > temp.txt
set /p TESTOUTPUT=< temp.txt
if %TESTOUTPUT% == %ouputTest1%
```

The problem is with the outputTest1 variable and the quotes in the string. I tried with double quotes like this:

```
set ouputTest1 = "The output of ""test.exe"" is OK"
```

But with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has three problems:

### Problem #1:

The line of script, `set ouputTest1 = "The output of "test.exe" is OK"` does not create a variable named `outputTest1`; instead it creates a variable named `outputTest1<space>`.  This is the reason why `%outputTest1%` will always be empty.

### Problem #2:

In a "set" statement, *everything* after the equal sign gets assigned--including the space and the outer quotes.  In your case, the content of the variable winds up being `<space>"The output of "test.exe" is OK"`.

### Problem #3:

Finally, you need to change your IF-compare.  The correct way to do it is as follows:

```
set "ouputTest1=The output of "test.exe" is OK"

test.exe -p 75 > temp.txt
set /p TESTOUTPUT=< temp.txt
if "%TESTOUTPUT%" == "%ouputTest1%" echo Equal
```

Answer (score 4):

Using delayed expansion seem to get round this, with or without surrounding quotes (`c` and `d` are unquoted):

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set a="The output of "test.exe" is OK"
set b="The output of "test.exe" is OK"

set "c=The output of "test.exe" is NOT OK"
set "d=The output of "test.exe" is NOT OK"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if !a!==!b! echo a and b match!
if !c!==!d! echo c and d match!

endlocal
```

Comment: @dbenham - It works with undefined variables, even without quotes! `if !a!==!b!` is enough, as the delayed expansion will _prevent_ syntax problems

Answer (score 1):

The answer that wmz has proposed seems like a solid one, but I thought I could still offer this alternative, for consideration.

Instead of reading the output (i.e. your temp.txt) into a variable, for comparison, you could instead write out your comparison string to another file and compare the files.  Something like the following:

```
echo The output of "test.exe" is OK>temp-expected.txt
fc temp.txt temp.expected.txt >NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" ( echo YAY ) else ( echo BOO )
```